# Convert (vectorize) code with per32-bit element conditional to SSE2 SSE3

Tags: optimization, assembly, sse, vectorization

I want to vectorize code for Core2. I think, I can use intrinsic functions from gcc or icc, and the SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3 instructions are allowed.

My code works on arrays of 8 uint32_t elements and it is like this (only hotspot is here):

```
const uint32_t p[8] = {2147483743, 2147483713, 2147483693, 2147483659, 
 2147483647, 2147483629, 2147483587, 2147483579};
void vector_mod_add(uint32_t *a /* a[8] */, uint32_t *b /* b[8] */) {
    int n;
    for(n=0;n<8;n++)
        a[n]+=b[n];
    for(n=0;n<8;n++)
        if(a[n]>=p[n])
            a[n]-=p[n];
}
```

Addition is rather easy, but I don't know how it is possible to do an conditional subtraction.

Also, I have no experience in manual vectorizing with SSE2, so, please, tell me how should I define all types here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write it as `a[n] -= p[n] & ~(a[n] < p[n])`.  Note that the `<` here is not the C one, it's the SSE one (`pcmpltd`) that returns -1 in each true element and 0 in each false element (to allow the AND operation), and `&~` is `pandn`.  Here is an attempt at the code:

```
__m128i a, p;
a = _mm_sub_epi32(a, _mm_andnot_si128(_mm_cmplt_epi32(a, p), p));
```

Note that this uses signed operations, and so your numbers will need to stay below `2^31 - 1` for it to work correctly.  If you need to go beyond that, change `_mm_cmplt_epi32(a, p)` to `_mm_cmplt_epi32(_mm_xor_si128(a, signs), _mm_xor_si128(p, signs))`, where `signs` is a vector of 32-bit words whose elements are all `0x80000000`.  Here is a version that seems like it will handle wider ranges more efficiently:

```
__m128i a, p;
a = _mm_sub_epi32(a, p);
a = _mm_add_epi32(a, _mm_and_si128(_mm_srai_epi32(a, 31), p));
```

Comment: but this will subtract a[n] from a[n], turning it to zero. I want each a[i] and b[i] to be in range `0..p[n]-1`. I can code this as `if(a[n]>p[n])` or as `a[n]=a[n]%p[n]`

Comment: Also, there is a MINPD/MINSD - but it is only for floats, and I have integers.

Comment: Can you translate this code with functions from `xmmintrin.h` or other `*intrin.h` ?

Comment: @osgx: Look at what I just changed it to.

Comment: Hmm.. signed is bad news, as I want to use `p` almost as big as `(2^31)-1`. Sum of `a` and `b` is often greater than 2^31.

Comment: @osgx: I have a version that works for that case now, but it needs some optimization.  I'll think about it some more.

Comment: @osgx: I just added some new stuff onto the end; see if it works.